# How to submit a number from one page to another

Tags: php, html, input, submit, categories

I am trying to take whatever category the user chooses and trying to take the number they pick and create the subcategorys accordingly in php
for example: If user picks Junk main category then as subcategorys there would be wood and metal.  If they pick Art as the main category then as subcategorys there would be painting and drawing.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kSBjp/).

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value=1 checked> Junk<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value=2> Lego<br>
<input type="radio" name="type" value=3> Art<br/>
<input type="radio" name="type" value=4> Code<br/>
<input type="radio" name="type" value=5> Minecraft<br/><br/>    
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
```

I know it's not alot but it would be so awsome if someone could help me out.

Comment: oops forgot jsfiddle link, here it is:http://jsfiddle.net/kSBjp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want something like this:

```
junk
    wood
    metal

art
    painting
    drawing
```

so it could be solved with 2-tier Ajax architecture, where the user will select the first option as `junk` or `art`. Then you could send the id (assuming its comming from the db) of `junk` or `art` using AJAX to a php file.

In that php file, you would run a db query to fetch corresponding sub-category, and return them. Now the AJAX function on success will receive sub-categories, and can be used to display another select box with sub-categories.

Hope that answers your query, any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. The easiest would be by doing a regular postback after which you render the page again with the new radio buttons you can then add since you've posted the value of the current form.

The other option would be more intuitive and desirable for the user: a javascript solution. This can either be a solution where you preload all possible options (so all options and their children) beforehand and you only render the relevant ones whenever the values of your inputs change. Alternatively you could use AJAX to do an asynchronous postback with the new value which then returns the possible subcategories, which you can then render.

Either way: there is quite a bit of coding involved that requires in-depth knowledge of how your system works, more insight than your jsFiddle gives. If you read up a bit on how you can deal with forms in serverside languages, that will help you with all three solutions. Reading up on DOM manipulation in Javascript will help you with the last two, and reading up on AJAX will help you with the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `form` and `$_POST`

#### Form

Change `your_action_file.php` with your `php` file:

```
<form action="your_action_file.php" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="type" value=1 checked> Junk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value=2> Lego<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value=3> Art<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value=4> Code<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value=5> Minecraft<br/><br/>    
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

#### In your action php file (your_action_file.php)

```
<?php

$type = $_POST['type'];

// Include desired code to execute
echo $type;

?>
```

Comment: It's a good example, and I added specifics for clarification, cheers.

Comment: OP can also use `echo "You chose " . $type;`